# Unity Camera vertically scrolling effect

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scroll, camera

I want to create a camera movement like idle miner tycoon. So the Camera should scroll vertically by panning with a typically scroll effect.

This is my code:

```
    Vector3 touchStart;
    public int upperLimit = 0;
    public int lowerLimit = 7000;
 
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            touchStart = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
 
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 direction = touchStart - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            float finalYPos = Camera.main.transform.position.y + direction.y;
            finalYPos = Mathf.Clamp(finalYPos, lowerLimit, upperLimit);
            Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.position.x, finalYPos, Camera.main.transform.position.z);
            Debug.Log(finalYPos);
        }
    }
```

But how can I make that the scrolling is ran out. Actually the movement is stopping  directly when I leave the mouse/thump.

Thank you for your help

Best regards

Comment: Do you want to click and drag to set the scroll direction and then have the camera keep scrolling after you release the mouse button?

Comment: yes, exactly. Like when you scroll a website on your smartphone. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Solution for everybody with the same problem:

```
   [SerializeField]
private Camera cam;

Vector3 touchStart;
private float topLimit = 0f;
private float bottomLimit = -2000.0f;

private Vector3 _curPosition;
private Vector3 _velocity;
private bool _underInertia;
private float _time = 0.0f;
public float SmoothTime = 2;

public Vector3 direction;

void Update()
{
    PanCamera();

    if (_underInertia && _time <= SmoothTime)
    {
        cam.transform.position += _velocity;
        float newY = Mathf.Clamp(cam.transform.position.y, bottomLimit, topLimit);
        cam.transform.position = new Vector3(cam.transform.position.x, newY, cam.transform.position.z);

        _velocity = Vector3.Lerp(_velocity, Vector3.zero, _time);
        _time += Time.smoothDeltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        _underInertia = false;
        _time = 0.0f;
    }
}


private void PanCamera()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        touchStart = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        _underInertia = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 _prevPosition = _curPosition;

        direction = touchStart - cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        float finalYPos = cam.transform.position.y + direction.y;
        Debug.Log("Old: " + finalYPos);
        finalYPos = Mathf.Clamp(finalYPos, bottomLimit, topLimit);
        Debug.Log("New: " + finalYPos);
        Vector3 desiredPosition = new Vector3(cam.transform.position.x, finalYPos, cam.transform.position.z);
        cam.transform.position = desiredPosition; 

        _curPosition = desiredPosition;
        _velocity = _curPosition - _prevPosition;

    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        _underInertia = true;

    }
}
```